# Aquifers and borehole wells in the UK

Tags: geospatial, uk

I want to be able to plot aquifers and borehole wells in the UK. I need to find out how far each aquifer and borehole well is from surrounding buildings and infrastructure.

Is the only way to do this using a base map?

Is there a way of downloading all UK infrastructure into QGIS version 3.10.0?

Comment: Infrastructure data tends to be closely held, to prevent nefarious use. But [opendata.se] is a more likely spot to find what is available.

Comment: Have you contacted the British geological Survey yet? Some Borehole data is [here](https://www.bgs.ac.uk/products/onshore/sobi.html) they would also likely have aquifer data too.

Comment: I have downloaded Dat from BGS on both borehole data, Aquifer and water wells. however, unlike their geoindex interactive map. which separates all three data bases. The downloaded data encompasses them all in one and I can not find any way of differentiating between e.g a water well and a borehole

Comment: Does anyone know how to use a Geopackage or Vector Tile (MB) in QGIS as I have downloaded the 'OS Open Zoomstack' data set to use for the infrastructure but cannot make the layer apear in QGIS

Comment: That's a question for gis se.

Comment: @Hornbydd I reported your comment in my answer there so it can appear more clearly. Please feel free to modify or add details on the web resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could dig in [Environment Agency Open Data](https://data.gov.uk/search?filters%5Bpublisher%5D=Environment%20Agency) on Data.gov.uk
- See also this page for [UK Groundwater ressources](http://apps.environment-agency.gov.uk/wiyby/37833.aspx)

From comments:

- @Hornbydd : See [British Geological Survey](https://www.bgs.ac.uk/products/onshore/sobi.html) website for boreholes